# Programmatically Get Navigation Controller from Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I used a "push" segue from a ViewController after using the menu in XCode Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller. I have a button on this presented view that slides in from the side that I would like to dismiss the pushed view. I realize there is a method:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But I don't have a pointer to the Navigation Controller I added through the XCode menu..

My App Delegate has the window's root view controller as my main ViewController - so I haven't done anything there after adding the Navigation Controller from the XCode menu.

How can I get a pointer to this added Navigation Controller so I can call the pop method programmatically on the pushed view controller? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct function to use, and will automatically return the navigation controller that you "pushed" into.

From the [UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/navigationController):

> **navigationController**
>   The nearest ancestor in the view controller hierarchy that is a navigation controller. (read-only)
>
> `@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UINavigationController`
>   *navigationController
>
> **Discussion**
>   If the receiver or one of its ancestors is a child of a navigation controller, this property contains the owning navigation
>   controller. This property is nil if the view controller is not
>   embedded inside a navigation controller.